# java regex problem

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have a string "July is busy". And I need the string without "July". How can I do it with using regex ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why "July"? First word? Word with capital letters? You have July elsewhere? Before "is"? Who knows.

Comment: `String strWithoutJuly = " is busy";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to remove the first word from a string?

Try

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("^\\s*\\w+\\s*", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But my problem is that my employer does not want any string function.

Comment: Wow, your "employer" sounds a lot more like an "instructor"

Comment: I dont know what will my employer say. But I think this is the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^July(.*)\$").matcher("July is busy");

// if you had a match, the extra would be here:
if (m.matches()) {

    // match count:
    m.groupCount();

    // ' is busy'
    String rightOfJuly = m.group(1);
}
```